# POO Java Classe conta

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde pessoal, estou a fazer exercicio para um curso de POO e tenho que um em que tenho que criar uma classe conta, no entanto já fiz o seguinte:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class conta {

```
String nome = "John";
String nome2 = "Doe";
int numerodeconta = 123456789;
int numerodeconta2 = 987654321;

public static void main(String args[]) {

float valordeconta;
float valordeconta2;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Quanto dinheiro tem o 1º Titular");
valordeconta = input.nextFloat();

System.out.println("Quanto dinheiro tem o 2º Titular");
valordeconta2 = input.nextInt();;


if (valordeconta >= valordeconta2) {
    System.out.println("o 1º Titular tem mais dinheiro que o 2º Titular");
} else {
    System.out.println("O 2º Titular tem mais dinheiro do que o 1º Titular");
}


}
```

}

a formadora diz me que não está correto e leva bastante tempo a corrigir os trabalhos e eu como não sei estou à procura de ajuda pois andei à procura e não encontrei nada semelhante, o objetivo é que criar uma única classe Conta e depois dois objetos dessa classe Conta. Depois comparar o saldo de ambas.

o que é que estou a fazer de errado ?

obrigado

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

Conforme a descrição que tu colocou do exercício, no meu entendimento será necessário criar uma classe chamada Conta com os atributos e métodos interessantes para esse contexto. Posteriormente deverá ser criado uma outra classe chamada ContaTeste para testa-la (Conta).

Uma introdução seria:

```
public class Conta {

   private String nome;
   private String numeroConta;
   private Long saldo;

   // Construtor
   // Implementar métodos getters e setters

}

public class ContaTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  Conta conta1 = new Conta();
  Conta conta2 = new Conta();
  //Usar método set para atribuir os valores para os atributos
  //nome, numeroConta e saldo

  if(conta1.getSaldo() >= conta2.getSaldo()) {
  // Implementar lógica da comparação
  }

}
```

É importante estudar sobre classes, atributos e métodos que isso vai facilitar o entendimento e irá conseguir completar o exemplo acima.
abraço

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).